# How to merge multi-line output to form a single line?

Tags: unix, shell

I want to join different line output to a single line like below.

```
$ cat new.txt | grep Full |  awk '{print $1}' 
09/01/2018
08/25/2018
08/18/2018
08/11/2018
08/04/2018
07/28/2018
07/21/2018
```

I want to join above output to a single line like

```
09/01/2018,08/25/2018
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

`tr` replaces every newline character with `,`, including the very last one (after `07/21/2018`). Then `sed` replaces `,` at the end with a newline to form a POSIX-compliant line without trailing `,`.

Please note `sed` is a text processing tool that by default works with one line at a time. Whatever leaves `tr` is a single line; it may be very long, depending on your input, and `sed` may no longer be the best tool to handle it.

I would reconsider the idea of having all the results in a single line, just to avoid such scenario. There are ways to replace this particular `sed` with a tool working with bytes (not lines). But even if you do this here, you'll still have a potentially very long line which is inconvenient to parse later.

OK, if you really need to do this then use the following command to create an arbitrarily large line. All parsing is done with tools operating on bytes:

```
head -c -1 | tr '\n' ',' && printf '\n'
```

`head` strips the last character, we blindly assume it's a newline; `tr` changes all remaining newlines into `,` characters; `printf` adds a trailing newline to make your result a POSIX-compliant line.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`paste`](https://manpage.me/?q=paste).

```
cat new.txt | grep Full |  awk '{print $1}' | paste -s -d,
```

Also, awk can do what both cat and grep can do, so

```
awk '/Full/ {print $1}' new.txt | paste -s -d,
```

Also, awk can format it's output, but it's less readable:

```
awk '/Full/ {printf "%s%s", (NR == 1 ? "" : ","), $1} END {print ""}' new.txt
```